# How do I determine how much Twilio storage I am consuming?

Tags: twilio

I am using the Twilio SMS Msg Rest API.

The Media messages (which contain photos) are stored on the twilio storage.  Where can I go to see how much of the storage (in MB) I am consuming?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While it is not a property of the [media instance resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/media#instance), you can find this info in Usage Records.

Check out the `mediastorage` param here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-records#usage-sms-mms

This is the amount of storage used by media stored for the account. Count is the number of stored media files, Usage is the number of megabytes, and Price is the price of storing the media. Example in Python:

```
# Download the Python helper library from twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID"
auth_token  = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

# A list of record objects with the properties described above
records = client.usage.records.today.list(category="mediastorage")
```